# Macport RPM macros settings

Tags: macos, macros, rpm, macports

I installed Macport on my Mac for using RPM. After successful installation (I think), "rpmbuild" and "rpm" command is accessible. But rpmbuild always failed.

I checked "rpm --showrc" and noticed that there are a lot of macros are missing. For example, %__spec_prep_cmd, %__spec_prep_post, %__spec_prep_template. Therefore I have to define all these macros in /opt/local/lib/rpm/macros.

Can someone help me why is that? Do I miss some steps during Macport installation?

Here is my installation steps:

1. Download OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion version: MacPorts-2.3.1-10.8-MountainLion.pkg
2. sudo port -v selfupdate
3. port search rpm
4. port install rpm54

Answer (score 0):

Edit the default macros file (likely in /opt/local/lib/rpm/macros)
to load (at least) macros.rpmbuild by uncommenting the line that
looks like:

```
...
#==============================================================================
# ---- rpmbuild macros.
#%%{load:%{_usrlibrpm}/macros.rpmbuild}
...
```

Remove the leading "#%"